# No data displayed by given a specific name and date

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is my table

[image]

and now I want to retrieve the data from `MySQL` to android based on name (Test) and month (01), but no data get displayed. Is there any mistake in my php ?

**My php code**

```
<?php
  define('HOST','127.0.0.1:3307');
  define('USER','root');
  define('PASS','');
  define('DB','androiddb');

  $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('unable to connect');

  $name = $_GET['name'];

  $month = $_GET['month'];

 $sql = "select * from information WHERE name= '". $name."' and month = '".$month."'";

  $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

  $result=array();

  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
      array_push($result,array('id'=>$row[0],'name'=>$row[1],'weather'=>$row[2],'date'=>$row[3],'status'=>$row[4],
      'time_in'=>$row[5], 'time_out'=>$row[6]));
  }

 echo (json_encode(array("result"=>$result)));

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a condition `month = ...` in your SQL statement but the table doesn't have a month column.

This should work:

```
$sql = "select * from information WHERE name= '". $name."' and MONTH(date) = '".$month."'";
```